# Why my codeigniter code about transaction does not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, transactions

My code is liked this:

```
$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE); //close Strict Mode
$this->db->trans_begin();
$updateArr = array('name'=>'test', 'age'=>22);
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->update('user_table', $updateArr);        
$logArr = array('created'=>'2015-07-30', 'content'=>'test' );
$this->db->set($logArr)->insert('log_table');       
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {              
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return false;
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return true;
}
```

1. Does codeigniter transactions support  activerecord?
2. When the first query `return false`, why does the second query `return true` ?

what am I doing wrong ? Please help me.

`I use MySQL InnoDB`

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html#strict-mode). So you have to remove line where you qualify FALSE parameter for `trans_strict()` method.

Comment: The codeigniter [Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html#strict-mode) said: `By default CodeIgniter runs all transactions in Strict Mode. When strict mode is enabled, if you are running multiple groups of transactions, if one group fails all groups will be rolled back. ` But I am not use `multiple groups of transactions`.And I had tried the suggestion , that does not work.

Comment: So what is second query from question no. 2?

Comment: The query also `return true` , but I want it to `$this->db->trans_rollback();`

Comment: Have you checked did your query return `FALSE` outside transaction?

Comment: The first query `$updateArr = array('name'=>'test', 'age'=>22);
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->update('user_table', $updateArr); ` , Need I do like this : to judge the `$this->db->update('user_table', $updateArr);` 's affacted_rows to do `$this->db->trans_rollback();`